# how to add video in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to put a video from YouTube on my page, so I used a script that I copied from my blog on Google Blogger, as follows:

```html
<div>
    <iframe 
      id="vid" 
      allowfullscreen=""
      class="YOUTUBE-iframe-video" 
      data-thumbnail-src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sjxDbz9HOnE/0.jpg" 
      frameborder="0"
      src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/sjxDbz9HOnEfeature=player_embedded" 
      height="300" 
      width="300">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And the method succeeded with these video,

I compared the video link used to the original link and found the following:

---

video link used: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/sjxDbz9HOnE?feature=player_embedded`

original video link: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjxDbz9HOnE&feature`

we know that almost all YouTube videos start with the phrase: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`

And from it the code that distinguishes the video is the phrase after it, which is: `sjxDbz9HOnE`

And from it to fetch any video we use the following link: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/__video_cod__?feature=player_embedded`

It also applies to the other link, which is about the video image, where: `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/__video_cod__/0.jpg`

---

But as I said, the method worked with me only with this video and tried to try another video, so the image of the video appears and when I click on it to play the video it does not work and displays an error message.

Comment: What error message?

Comment: "The video is not available"

Comment: What other video?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G94jQi0UGr0

Answer (score 1):

you should use a valid video url. your url "https://www.youtube.com/embed/sjxDbz9HOnEfeature=player_embedded" is dead.